# JQuery AJAX post variable to custom php file in WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I was tried to make JQuery AJAX post variable to custom php file in WordPress. But it doesn't work at all.
`$column_filter_text = $_POST['filtertext'];`
Javascript success but returns undefined value. Actually the variable was not passing from JQuery AJAX to Php file. The following are the code below:
database-table-data.php in the WordPress theme folder.

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
global $wpdb;
$column_filter_text = $_POST['filtertext'];
echo "<script>console.log('php post variable: '" . $column_filter_text . ");</script>";
$result = $wpdb->get_results ("
    SELECT " . $column_filter_text . " FROM wpgw_wpdatatable_1");
foreach ( $result as $row )
{
   echo $row . "<br>";
    $return_arr[] = array("filter_column_data" => $row);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Javascript file code:

```
columnfiltertext = "bmc";
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://********.com/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/database-table-data.php", 
    method: "post", 
    //data: { "message":$('#input-message').val(),"sender":$('#sender').val(),"receiver":$('#receiver').val()},you can pass the values directly like this or else you can store it in variables and can pass
    data: { filtertext: "bmc" }, //"column_filter_number":column_filter_number},
    success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var filter_column_data = response[i].filter_column_data;
                //alert(filter_column_data);
                console.log(i + ":" + filter_column_data);
                }
        },
     error: function() {
    alert('Not OKay');
    } 
   });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to getting data from the database

Add this code to the function.php theme file

```
<?php
    function database_table_data()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $column_filter_text = $_POST['column_filter_text'];
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT " . $column_filter_text . " FROM wpgw_wpdatatable_1");
        if($result){
            echo json_encode($result);
        } else {
            echo json_encode('record not fount');
        }
        wp_die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_database_table_data', 'database_table_data');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_database_table_data', 'database_table_data');
?>
```

Javascript file code:

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $('button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var columnfiltertext = "bmc";
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "https://********.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=database_table_data",
                data: { column_filter_text: columnfiltertext },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: The output of your code shows 'record not fount' mesage box, that means the javascript variable is not passing to ajax admin-ajax.php.

Comment: Direct query without $_POST variable is working!

Comment: I got the solution from https://awhitepixel.com/blog/wordpress-use-ajax/